# Get Mouse Position in SharpDX relative to window

Tags: c#, position, cursor, sharpdx

How can I get the Position of the Cursor in C# relative to the window im in?
I am using SharpDX and i tried

```
System.Drawing.Point loc = Cursor.Position;
```

and

```
System.Drawing.Point loc = Control.MousePosition;
```

which gave me the absolute X and Y Coordinates of the Cursor (X:0 and Y:0 being in the top left corner of my screen and not my window).

Is there something implemented in SharpDX to get this done?
I found nothing that worked for me on the internet

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using a winform?   If so, look for mouse events for controls.

If you are not using Visual studio then you will have to add the event.  The controls sample can be found here -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx

Sharpdx does not itself deal with mouse at all from my recollection.  You need to understand the field of movement for the mouse within the window and convert to what ever input stream you need.

Comment: No where did I say mouse clicks, I sent you the link the mousemove event for the form which is a control which is what your form is.  The event in the form is triggered it passes the current location of the mouse in the object System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs.  This has the X and Y co-ordinate of the mouse in the current control.